# Facemark or Kazemi in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, face-detection, opencv3.1, facial-identification

I have been working on integrating OpenCV in android and i am able to do it successfully. Through the Java presets and **Haarcascades** i am able to detect **Face**, **Nose**, **Mouth** at runtime.

Now may next task is to detect facial landmarks at runtime. After a lot of searching i ended up with **Dlib** and **Flandmark**. I tried to implement both. When i implemented Dlib my camera's frames rate dropped from 15 fps to 1-2 fps and moreover the landmarks were also not detected. In Flandmark the the code was unable to find the .dat file from the raw folder. After more search on Google i found that OpenCV 3.4.1 has integrated Facemark and there is no need to implement any third party libraries for landmark detection.

At this point i can't find any example or documentation on how i can implement *Facemark* or *Kazemi* directly on the retuned *mat* in *onCameraFrame* and detect **facial landmarks** from there.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The facial landmark Kazemi stuff is not a part of the core opencv package it is one of the extensions: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Personally I think they should make that module part of the core since so many people access to the facial landmarks.